# JMeter HTTP Response Code 200

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am newbie on using jmeter. I have error display on view result tree Listener when I try to make test plan about create registration. Anybody can tell me about what is the mean of this error? I have read from another forum that he solved the http response 200 by add "Cookie manager" element on "thread group" (reference : http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Getting-HTTP-Response-200-instead-of-500-td518231.html ).
But on my test plan, the cookie manager already added. Please let me know if there is any advice about this?

The sampler result display like below:

```
Thread Name: Registration 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-10-07 11:18:26 SGT
Load time: 643
Latency: 633
Size in bytes: 29706
Headers size in bytes: 155
Body size in bytes: 29551
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2013 03:18:27 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
DataEncoding: ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when a top level sample returns a 200 OK and failed status, it means a failed embedded resource sample or a failed assertion. Do you have embedded resource showing in the listener?

Comment: Hi Mr. Alon, thank you for your comment. i'm really new user on jmeter. could you tell me how to know that there is embedded resource, is it means scripting on beanshell? or like there is TOKENvalue that reference from struts apache? because i just rebuild from the complex test plan that given by my senior and i just create from that test plan, the newest simple test plan (like i said before : just for create registration)

Comment: Hi it is fairly simple. On your sampler dashboard did you tick the checkbox that states: "Retrieve Embedded Resources" ? If so, you do use embedded resources. When you enable the "View Results in Tree" listener, you should see under the top level sample/response, sub samples. One of them should be red (while the others are green).

Comment: :) thank you Mr. Alon. after i checked, i found it caused a failed assertion for If Controller.